# Calculations between form input fields

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I would like to ask for a little help. I am a total beginner with Vue but doing a simple calculator.

The problem is : three forms with two values entered and calculate in third.

Preferebly I would have all three blank and when data is enetered to two the calculation is rendered in the third. It doesn’t matter which two. Unfortunately I couldn’t figure it out so I went with two specific values and calculate in third using compute. I would like this to be so that no matter which two you enter the third will show the calculation I need.

Further, I have multiple if statements as you can see from the code. I am sure there is a much nicer way to code this.
At the end of the day my code works but will become very long when using multiple if statements that I need.

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    value1: null,
    value2: null
  },
  computed: {
    a_ratio() {
      var a_number = parseInt(this.value2) / parseInt(this.value1);
      return a_number.toFixed(1);
    },

    calculation() {
      if (this.value1 < 100 && this.value2 > 0) {
        var val = parseInt(this.value2) / 10 || 0;
        return val.toFixed(1);
      }
      if (this.value1 >= 100 && this.value2 > 0) {
        var val = parseInt(this.value2) / 20 || 0;
        return val.toFixed(1);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: What is the significance of the values `10` and `20`? Is this denominator the only thing that will differ in each of the if statements? My suggestion is to look for patterns that can help you reduce the amount of code to write. For example, `this.value1` isn't used in either of your examples here. Can it be used to calculate the `10` or the `20` so that you can reduce the if statements to a line or two?

Comment: What is the significance of `a_ratio`? Could you describe the relevant calculation in words, with examples of how it should work differently depending on which inputs the user populates? What should happen if the user populates two of the inputs and then tries to edit the input containing the result?

Comment: 10 and 20 are values used to calculate. They are fixed but depending on value1 the calculation is shown. There is another calculation and if statement going on that I show in html table. It's pretty much the same concept as an example I posted. 

a_ratio is another calculation that can be had when entering two out of three input fields. My goal here is to be able to calculate one field no matter which two fields are entered so actually a_ratio should be in there with value1 and value2.

Answer (score 0):

So much prettier :)

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    value1: null,
    value2: null
  },
  computed: {
    a_ratio() {
      var a_number = parseInt(this.value2) / parseInt(this.value1);
      return a_number.toFixed(1);
    },

    calculation() {
      if (this.value2 <= 0) return;
      let divider;

      if (this.value1 < 100) {
        divider = 10;
      } else if (this.value1 >= 100) {
        divider = 20;
      }

      return (parseInt(this.value2) / divider || 0).toFixed(1);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this! It will cut down my code considerably!